# How to Firebase set into a doc map value

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase collections structure that I would like to update however only the phonebook(map) section of a specified doc.

[image]

The below code was my attempt however I get the error `Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments`. I'm new to Firebase so I think the is a concept in not understanding here

```
insertPhonebookEntry(entry: any) {
  if (entry.id) {
    this.db.doc(entry.id).set({
    PhoneBook: {
      Name: entry.name,
      PhoneNumber: entry.phonenumber
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't say what exactly `entry.id` is in your case, I'm going to assume that it's just the random ID that Firestore assigned to the document you're trying to fetch.  That's not enough information to query it back.  You'll need to specify the name of the collection as well, in order to provide a full path to the document:

```
this.db.collection('PhonebookEntries').doc(entry.id).set(...)
```

Comment: Okay, this works but overrides the data already stored into the document. it does not add to the already existing `PhoneBook` map structure

Comment: It sounds like you have a different problem now than the first one.  Look into using update rather than set.  If you're still having problems, please ask a new question and describe what's not working the way you expect.